# Geany "Syntax coloring" isn't functioning properly

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, geany

I'm writing a python script on Geany.
I really don't know what I did but it seems Geany isn't coloring python syntax properly in the editor.
Some python commands and arguments aren't marked as blue such as "import,def,class,True."
And the file seems messy
When I run it it works just fine but it's really hard to write like that
Anybody knows how to get it back?

Comment: Have a look to the basic Python configuration : https://wiki.geany.org/config/python

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling 
Document -> setfile type -> python source script...